# Gstreamer close sink after disconnecting camera

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

> I'm using Gstreamer with rtspsrc with an RTSP camera and when I dosconnect the camera from the computer the autovideosink stays open. How do I make it close automatically once I disconnect the camera?

I tried setting a timeout but that didn't work. I have no leads.

Comment: Inspect bus Messages and in case of disconnect or Errors shutdown the pipeline

Comment: @Christoph Can you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Just Look into gstreamer Basic Tutorial 1 how to use bus

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Christoph, add watch on the message bus, GStreaner uses message bus to communicate between different parts of pipeline, for example conveying events, warnings, errors between different elements.

So when the sensor is disconnected, the source element would post a warning or error on the message bus, you need to watch for this and then use `GST_RTSP_FILTER_REMOVE` to shut down all active clients.

Add this callback function to the code

```
GstRTSPFilterResult client_filter(GstRTSPServer* server,
                                  GstRTSPClient* client,
                                  gpointer       user_data) {
    /* Simple filter that shuts down all clients. */
    return GST_RTSP_FILTER_REMOVE;
}
```

And when you receive the sensor disconnect error on the bus, just call following where `server` being your `GstRTSPServer` instance.

```
gst_rtsp_server_client_filter(server, client_filter, NULL);
```